# How do I spread a list out with spacers?

Tags: ruby

I want to evenly spread out a list, like `[1,2,3,4]`, into a different list, like `[1, nil, nil, 2, nil, nil, 3, nil, 4, nil]`, based on how big I want the new list to be.

So
`[1, 2, 3, 4]` to a list with a size of 9 would be: `[1, nil, nil, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4, nil]`

And `[1,2,3,4]` to a list with a size of 4 would be: `[1,2,3,4]`

I will need to spread "uneven" spacers, which should go from left to right - look at my first example.

---

I answered my own question below.

Comment: @theTinMan I get that, but I was trying to share my solution I made, with my answer below. I don't care about the logic that people use, and it's an algorithmic question that's hard to wrap your head around. But I do answer my own question below

Comment: OK. That's fair. Using nils inside an array that way seems like a questionable use of nils but that's a programmer's choice.

Comment: @theTinMan I did this mainly to then map over it - I was trying to create "long term assignments" in a homework planner I'm working on, so I thought the best way to create evenly spaced "work periods" was to create a list and add spaces, so I though this would be a good way of taking the work-periods and spacing them out (after they are mapped to due dates). I also made the gem so you can change the spacer from a nil object to something else (3rd argument, or spacer: [object]). Also, thanks for welcoming me, but you're about a year late :D

Comment: (Please do not encourage anyone to cross-post. It's _never_ a good idea.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thought it was encouraged... I guess you live and learn, right?

Comment: @penne12: Indeed. :) Cross-posting has always been frowned upon on the internet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting), though some communities allow it in limited fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make a gem for this: `gem install CreamCheese`

After installing and requiring the gem (`require 'CreamCheese'`), you can spread out a list with the knife.

```
require 'CreamCheese'
CreamCheese::Knife.spread [1,2,3,4], 9 #=> [1, nil, nil, 2, nil, 3, nil, 4, nil]
CreamCheese::Knife.spread [1,2,3,4], 4 #=> [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity.  Why would you want to do this?  I'm not sure how storing a bunch of nil values could be of much use.

Comment: @m8ss I did this mainly to then map over it - I was trying to create "long term assignments" in a homework planner I'm working on, so I thought the best way to create evenly spaced "work periods" was to create a list and add spaces, so I though this would be a good way of taking the work-periods and spacing them out (after they are mapped to due dates). I also made the gem so you can change the spacer from a nil object to something else (3rd argument, or `spacer: [object]`)

Comment: So I use something like: `CreamCheese::Knife.spread([work period, work period, etc], self.days_until_due).each_with_index.map {|work_period, i| work_period.due_date = (i + 1).days.from_now}` (the code looks a lot better with formatting, and not all in one line :D)

Comment: Hey, if that works for you then great.  I have been burned by nil values in the past. I would recommend you put something of more meaning as a spacer like `:free_time` or something.

Comment: @m8ss Yeah it works pretty well. Hopefully it holds up :D

Comment: If you wish to offer an answer, you must present your code. You could mention that you converted it to a gem, but that is secondary.

Comment: @CarySwoveland There are many answers pointing to gems, and they give code samples on how the gem works, but not the gem itself. I thought that would be a nice solution, instead of posting the code, but I'll post it if you think I should.

Comment: What do you mean by that? My answer has a gem, and it explains it's use. This is like saying that all answers need binary. There are plenty of answers that say "Trying using this Gem, like this...". If it's a problem that I made the gem, that somewhat makes sense, but I would like to know the problem with my answer for future reference.

Comment: I'm simply saying that you've not provided a link to the gem. I don't care if the code is here or at the link, though links are sometimes broken.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm confused. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94499/discussion-between-penne12-and-cary-swoveland).

Comment: I gotta say, CreamCheese is a funny name for this.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go as far as using a gem for this one, as it can be solved in a couple of lines of Ruby. Unfortunately, you don't specify precisely how you want to handle cases where the spread isn't even ("even" being when each item is followed by the same number of spacers).

In the simple case of an even spread:

```
# The general case
spread_array = array.flat_map {|el| [el] + [spacer] * (spread / array.size - 1)

# An example
[1, 3].flat_map {|el| [el] + [nil] * 2 } #=> [1, nil, nil, 3, nil, nil]
```

If you wish to add the leftover spacing after the leftmost elements, you can use this:

```
# Extra spread goes on the leftmost items
spread_array = array.flat_map.with_index do |el, i|
  [el] + [spacer] * (spread / array.size - (i < spread % array.size ? 0 : 1))
end
```

Comment: If you look at my example with a list size of 9, I mean to add the leftover spacing from left to right, which will happen often for what I'm doing. I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: @penne12 I've revised the answer to include your specific case.